# Listbox going to next item

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox that I can load items into.

How can I click a button where it will highlight the next item and paste it into a textbox?

```
Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

First, add a button control to your form, and then wire up an event handler method to its `Click` event.

Next, you'll have to write some code—you weren't hoping I was going to write it *for* you, were you?. Start with the knowledge that all of the items in a `ListBox` are accessible through the [`Items` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx). So you could simply select the `n + 1` item, where `n` is the index of the currently selected item.

I'm not sure what you mean by "copy it to a textbox". ListBox items can't be copied to a textbox. Do you want to copy the text displayed for the item to a textbox? If so, call the `ToString` method of the individual item, and add it to the clipboard using the appropriate methods of the [`Clipboard` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  If ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 AndAlso ListBox1.SelectedIndex < ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  If ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 AndAlso ListBox1.SelectedIndex < ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
    TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Edited, SelectedIndex can be -1.